# Solving system of linear equations with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Stuck on this problem:

> Given
> $$2^x + 5^y = 2^y +5^x = 7/10$$
> Find $(x + y)^{-1}$

I know it's a system of linear equations problem but unsure how to isolate one variable to get the other. Not looking for a solution but just guidance on how to solve it.

Comment: By inspection, $x=y=-1$ is a solution.  And by inspection, I mean using the fact that $$\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac{a+b}{ab}.$$  Conveniently, $2+5=7$ and $2\times5=10$.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I wasn't aware of that one!